# InputMissMatchException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read data about MMORPG characters from a .txt file and then filter on experience (minimum experience). But I'm getting this exception, which I know the meaning of but I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not good at java, I'm a beginner actually. Can someone please explain this to me? Probably I'm doing something very stupid.

This is my code:

**Karakter (Character):**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Karakter {

 private String name;
 private int experience;
 private int maxHealthPoints;
 private int healthPoints;
 private int maxGreed;
 private int greed;

 public Karakter(String nm, int exp, int mHP, int hp, int mG, int g)
 {
  name = nm;
  experience = exp;
  maxHealthPoints = mHP;
  healthPoints = hp;
  maxGreed = mG;
  greed = g;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  String s = "";
  s += getName(); 
  s += getExperience();
  s += getMaxHealthPoints();
  s += getHealthPoints();
  s += getMaxGreed(); 
  s += getGreed();
  return s;
 }

 public static Karakter read(Scanner sc)
 {
  String name = sc.next();
  int experience = sc.nextInt();
  int maxHealthPoints = sc.nextInt();
  int healthPoints = sc.nextInt();
  int maxGreed = sc.nextInt();
  int greed = sc.nextInt();
  return new Karakter(name, experience, maxHealthPoints, healthPoints, maxGreed, greed);
 }

 public boolean hasExperience(int min)
 {
  return experience >= min;
 }
 // returns true if Krakters have the same name
 public boolean equals(Object other)
 {
  if(!(other instanceof Karakter))
  {
   return false;
  }
  else
  {
   Karakter that = (Karakter) other;
   return that.name == this.name;
  }
 }

 public String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }

 public int getExperience()
 {
  return experience;
 }

 public int getMaxHealthPoints()
 {
  return maxHealthPoints;
 }

 public int getHealthPoints()
 {
  return healthPoints;
 }

 public int getMaxGreed()
 {
  return maxGreed;
 }

 public int getGreed()
 {
  return greed;
 }


}
```

**Karakters (Characters):**

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Karakters {



private ArrayList<Karakter> kars = new ArrayList<Karakter>();

 public void voegToe(Karakter kar)
 {
  if(!kars.contains(kar))
  {
   kars.add(kar);
  }
 }

 // returns an arraylist of characters with exp >= minexp

 public ArrayList<Karakter> karaktersVanaf(int minExperience)
 {
  Karakter kar = null;
  for(int i = 0; i < kars.size(); i++)
  {
   if(kar.hasExperience(minExperience))
    kars.add(kar);
  }
  return kars;
 }

 public static Karakters read(String infile)
 {
  Karakters k = new Karakters();
  try
  {
   FileReader fr = new FileReader(infile);
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
   int aantal = sc.nextInt();
   for(int i = 0; i < aantal ; i++)
   {
    Karakter kar = Karakter.read(sc);
    k.kars.add(kar);
   }
   fr.close();
  }
  catch(IOException iox)
  {
   System.out.println(iox);
   return null;
  }
  return k;
 }

}
```

**KarakterZoeker (Main method):**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class KarakterZoeker {


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {


  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Karakters kars = Karakters.read("infile.txt");

  System.out.println("Welke experience wilt u minimaal?");
  int minExp = sc.nextInt();

  ArrayList<Karakter> s = kars.karaktersVanaf(minExp);

  System.out.println(s.toString());

 }

 }
```

**And this is the error:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Karakter.read(Karakter.java:38)
 at Karakters.read(Karakters.java:41)
 at KarakterZoeker.main(KarakterZoeker.java:14)
```

**these lines:**

```
Karakter kar = Karakter.read(sc);  (in Karakters)
int experience = sc.nextInt();   (in Karakter)
Karakters kars = Karakters.read("infile.txt");  (in KarakterZoeker)
```

**this is the txt file:**

```
2
name = Dursley
experience = 15
maxHealthPoints = 20
healthPoints = 10
maxGreed = 3
greed = 1
name = Aragorn
experience = 45
maxHealthPoints = 40
healthPoints = 30
maxGreed = 20
greed = 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on this line:

```
int experience = sc.nextInt();
```

You are trying to read a "int" but what the scanner reads is a string `"experience"`

From this line in your .txt file:

```
experience = 15
```

So you have to read two strings  ( 1<sup>st</sup>  is "experience" and 2<sup>nd</sup> is  "="  ) and then you will be able to read an int ( 15 )  and so on.

The first one didn't failed, because `name` was assigned a String, but if you log what you read, you've got: "name" instead of the real name.

An alternative is to let the `ResourceBundle` class do the read for you. Or even the `Properties` class.

With ResourceBundle you would do something like:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Karakters");
String exp = bundle.getString("experience");
int experience = Integer.parseInt( exp );
```

And you would have to name that as: `Karakters.properties`

**EDIT**

I have added a sample on how I would do this using `ResouceBundle`

Answer (score 1):

[`InputMismatchException`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is *thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type*.

So, my guess is that you are calling `nextInt` when the next token isn't actually an `Integer`.

**EDIT**

You need to be careful when reading that file, because you have labels that count as tokens. For instance, when you have:

```
maxHealthPoints = 20 ,
```

You have three tokens: "maxHealthPoints", "=", and "20". The problem is that you are ignoring both the label (before "=") and the equal sign. My advice? Read your file line by line and use the `Scanner` to parse each line. Alternatively, remove the labels and the equal sign from the file, leaving just the values you want to extract.

Comment: So I have to use nextLine()? and then how can I only take the Integer?  sorry I'm a noob :P

Comment: You have to take the first two tokens (label and equal sign), and only then you can retrieve the value that you want. For instance, to retrieve `20` in `maxHealthPoints = 20`, you'd have to call: `next()`, `next()`, and finally `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `next()` twice fixed the problem. After that I got a `NullPointerException` in my `karaktersVanaf(minExp)` in Karakters. To fix this I added these lines to my code:

```
public ArrayList<Karakter> karaktersVanaf(int minExperience) throws           FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("infile.txt")); // --------line 1
    Karakter kar = Karakter.read(sc); // ------------ line 2
    for(int i = 0; i < kars.size(); i++)
    {
        if(kar.hasExperience(minExperience))
            kars.add(kar);
    }
    return kars;
}
```

But now I'm seeing the `InputMissMatschException` again! I don't know what I'm doing wrong! I may be doing something totally wrong so be ready to laugh.

By th way, I don't have 15 experience points yet, that's why I can't vote for you just now. I will do that as soon as I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Each time your reader does a nextInt() or nextString(), it doesn't read the next line, it reads the next characters separated by whitespace (space or newline).  The simplest way to fix your problem would be to remove the "name =", "experience =", and just put the unique data on each line.

So your file would look like:

```
2
Dursley
15
20
10
3
1
Aragorn
45
40
30
20
10
```

And then your code will work as is.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a way to read using ResourceBundle.

I leave it here, I hope you find it useful:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ktr {
       public static void main( String [] args ) {

           ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("k");
           String names = b.getString("names");

           List<K> l = new ArrayList<K>();
           for( String name : names.split(",")){
               l.add( K.read( name, b ));
           }

           System.out.println( l );
       }
}

class K {

    private String name;
    private int maxHealthPoints;
    private int maxGreed;
    // etc.. 

    public static K read( String name, ResourceBundle b ) {
        K k = new K();
        k.name              = name;
        k.maxHealthPoints   = 
            Integer.parseInt(b.getString( name + ".maxHealthPoints") );

        k.maxGreed          = 
            Integer.parseInt(b.getString( name + ".maxGreed") );
        // you get the idea 
        return k;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s{maxHealthPoints=%d, maxGreed=%d}", 
                                name, maxHealthPoints, maxGreed);
    }
}
```

k.properties

```
names=Dursley,Aragorn
Dursley.maxHealthPoints=20
Dursley.maxGreed=3

Aragorn.maxHealthPoints=40
Aragorn.maxGreed=20
```

Output:

```
java Ktr
[Dursley{maxHealthPoints=20, maxGreed=3}, Aragorn{maxHealthPoints=40, maxGreed=20}]
```